# How can I check if a string contains a given set of characters (disregarding order) using Regex?

Tags: regex, string, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to write a regular expression in order to check if a given string contains a set of characters, however, the string MUST contain ALL of the characters, disregarding the order of appearance.
For example:

```
var myString = "howdyhow";
var toMatch = "hyo";
```

The string myString contains all the characters of the string toMatch. 
What I need is something similar to the regex [hyo], but instead of matching occurrences of h OR y OR o, I need it to match occurrences of h AND y AND o (disregarding the order or 'distance' between the characters).

Comment: I'm afraid a regex can't suit this need, I guess you'll have to iterate over each char of toMatch and check whether it is present in myString.

Comment: 'var' in your example suggests you are using a programming language.  So, just have 3 REs (/h/, /y/ /o/) and use an AND clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can construct a **lookahead** based regex from 2nd string and the call `RegExp.test` method:

```
var re = new RegExp( toMatch.split('').map(function(item) { 
              return "(?=.*?" + item + ")"; }).join('') );
//=> re = /(?=.*?h)(?=.*?y)(?=.*?o)/

var matched = re.test(myString);
```

Lookaheads in `/(?=.*?h)(?=.*?y)(?=.*?o)/` will make sure that all characters of 2nd string are matched in first string irrespective of their positions.

Answer (score 0):

I know its not Regex, but i would personally use `Contains`

```
if(value.Contains("h") && value.Contains("y") & value.Contains("o")) {}
```